# TreeSet not printing anything

Tags: java, file, text

I am trying to receive a file from my java directory, gather all the words in the document, put all the words into a `TreeSet`, and then print out the entire `TreeSet` of words. When I try the program, All that prints out from the `TreeSet` in the console is

```
Input file: 
trees.docx
[]
```

It just ends with these empty brackets.Note: Inside the trees.docx file is only the words "trees and stuff". Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class CountWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input file: ");
        String fileName = sc.next();
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        Set<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();

        // only happens if there is a next string
        while(in.hasNext()){
            words.add(in.next()); //adds this string to the treeSet initialized above
        }
        System.out.println(words); // prints the treeSet
    }
}
```

Comment: Java can't really read docx files  as plain-text...

Comment: You need to use a lib like [`Apache POI`](https://poi.apache.org/) if you want to read Microsoft files

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I tried this on my PC with a .txt file and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot read docx files. Either use external software to read Microsoft files or try another file type like .txt.